# A simple todoApp checkbox issue

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a simple todoApp about DOM manipulation.

```js
const classNames = {
  TODO_ITEM: 'todo-container',
  TODO_CHECKBOX: 'todo-checkbox',
  TODO_TEXT: 'todo-text',
  TODO_DELETE: 'todo-delete',
}

const list = document.getElementById('todo-list')
const itemCountSpan = document.getElementById('item-count')
const uncheckedCountSpan = document.getElementById('unchecked-count')
let count = 0;
let checkedCount = 0;
let todo;
function newTodo() {
 todo = prompt("Please enter to do task","enter here")
 count++;
 const markup = `<li><input type="checkbox" id=${todo} name="feature"
       value=${todo} data-ischecked = "false" />
   <label for=${todo}>${todo}</label></li>`
 list.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",markup)
 itemCountSpan.innerHTML = count;
 document.getElementById(todo).addEventListener("click",check);
}

function check(){
 let article = document.getElementById(todo);
 if(article.dataset.ischecked == "false"){
  article.dataset.ischecked = "true";
  checkedCount++;
  uncheckedCountSpan.innerHTML = checkedCount
 }
 else{
  article.dataset.ischecked = "false";
  checkedCount--;
  uncheckedCountSpan.innerHTML = checkedCount
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TODO App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container center">
      <h1 class="center title">My TODO App</h1>
      <div class="flow-right controls">
        <span>Item count: <span id="item-count">0</span></span>
        <span>Unchecked count: <span id="unchecked-count">0</span></span>
      </div>
      <button class="button center" onClick="newTodo()">New TODO</button>
      <ul id="todo-list" class="todo-list"></ul>
    </div>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, the checked feature is not what I expected. When I click on the checkbox, the total value should increase/decrease accordingly, but the number is toggling between 0 and 1.

What is the way to fix this? thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why Yours Is Not Working**

You're storing the most recently added item's ID as a variable called `todo`. That means in your `check()` function, the line...

```
let article = document.getElementById(todo);
```

...will always refer to the *last item added*. It's just toggling the `data-ischecked` back and forth on whichever the last item is.

---

**How To Fix It**

You want the click event to refer to the checkbox that's *being clicked*. We can do this by adding a parameter to the `check()` function, called `event`. With this, `event.target` will allow us to refer to the element that's been clicked.

```
function check(event) {
    let article = event.target; //This is the clicked checkbox!
}
```

(Given this, the `todo` variable no longer needs to be global.)

---

**One Other Important Note**

I'd highly advise against using `todo` as the element ID, because your ID cannot have spaces in it. Any time a to-do is entered with a space, your current code will throw an error.

Given that you're not allowing the removal of items, you could set it to something like `"todo-" + count` so that your IDs would be `todo-0`, `todo-1`, `todo-2`, etc.

I've implemented this in the code below as well, allowing you to add spaces in your to-do items.

```js
const classNames = {
  TODO_ITEM: 'todo-container',
  TODO_CHECKBOX: 'todo-checkbox',
  TODO_TEXT: 'todo-text',
  TODO_DELETE: 'todo-delete',
}

const list = document.getElementById('todo-list')
const itemCountSpan = document.getElementById('item-count')
const uncheckedCountSpan = document.getElementById('unchecked-count')
let count = 0;
let checkedCount = 0;

function newTodo() {
  var todo = prompt("Please enter to do task", "enter here");
  var newId = "todo" + count;
  count++;
  const markup = `<li><input type="checkbox" id=${newId} name="feature"
       value=${todo} data-ischecked = "false" />
   <label for=${todo}>${todo}</label></li>`
  list.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", markup)
  itemCountSpan.innerHTML = count;
  document.getElementById(newId).addEventListener("click", check);
}

function check(event) {
  let article = event.target;
  if (article.dataset.ischecked == "false") {
    article.dataset.ischecked = "true";
    checkedCount++;
    uncheckedCountSpan.innerHTML = checkedCount
  } else {
    article.dataset.ischecked = "false";
    checkedCount--;
    uncheckedCountSpan.innerHTML = checkedCount
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>TODO App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container center">
    <h1 class="center title">My TODO App</h1>
    <div class="flow-right controls">
      <span>Item count: <span id="item-count">0</span></span>
      <span>Unchecked count: <span id="unchecked-count">0</span></span>
    </div>
    <button class="button center" onClick="newTodo()">New TODO</button>
    <ul id="todo-list" class="todo-list"></ul>
  </div>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Yo need to pass a reference to the checked element. Something like this:

```
...
function check(evt){
    let article = document.getElementById(evt.target.id);
...
}
```

Then yor snippet will work:

```js
const classNames = {
  TODO_ITEM: 'todo-container',
  TODO_CHECKBOX: 'todo-checkbox',
  TODO_TEXT: 'todo-text',
  TODO_DELETE: 'todo-delete',
}

const list = document.getElementById('todo-list')
const itemCountSpan = document.getElementById('item-count')
const uncheckedCountSpan = document.getElementById('unchecked-count')
let count = 0;
let checkedCount = 0;
let todo;
function newTodo() {
 todo = prompt("Please enter to do task","enter here")
 count++;
 const markup = `<li><input type="checkbox" id=${todo} name="feature"
       value=${todo} data-ischecked = "false" />
   <label for=${todo}>${todo}</label></li>`
 list.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",markup)
 itemCountSpan.innerHTML = count;
 document.getElementById(todo).addEventListener("click",check);
}

function check(evt){
 let article = document.getElementById(evt.target.id);
 if(article.dataset.ischecked == "false"){
  article.dataset.ischecked = "true";
  checkedCount++;
  uncheckedCountSpan.innerHTML = checkedCount
 }
 else{
  article.dataset.ischecked = "false";
  checkedCount--;
  uncheckedCountSpan.innerHTML = checkedCount
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TODO App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container center">
      <h1 class="center title">My TODO App</h1>
      <div class="flow-right controls">
        <span>Item count: <span id="item-count">0</span></span>
        <span>Unchecked count: <span id="unchecked-count">0</span></span>
      </div>
      <button class="button center" onClick="newTodo()">New TODO</button>
      <ul id="todo-list" class="todo-list"></ul>
    </div>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```